# Problema com PhoneGap

Tags: apache-cordova

**Como posso resolver meu problema?**

Eu digito:

```
C:\Users\Micro>cd MyApp

C:\Users\Micro\MyApp>phonegap run android
```

Então aparece:

```
[phonegap] executing 'cordova run android' ...
Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting
it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try uptade your 'PATH' to
include path to valid SDK directory. 

C:\Users\Micro\MyApp>
```

Comment: Ja verificou que a variavel de sistema `ANDROID_HOME` [existe](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)?

Comment: Não existe, o que eu faço?

Answer (score 0):

Precisa de adicionar a variável `ANDROID_HOME` ao sistema.

Abra o PowerShell e escreva o seguinte:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("ANDROID_HOME", "C:\ installation location \android-sdk", "User")
```

(Nao se esqueça de reiniciar a linha de comandos de onde esta a invocar o phonegap depois de criar a variável)

Comment: Agora apareceu:   [phonegap] executing 'cordova run android' ...   Error: 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable is set to non-existent path: C:\installation location \android-sdk    Try uptade it manually to point to valid SDK directory.

Comment: @JoãoVitor entendeu-me mal, quando define a variavel tem de por o caminho para o seu android-sdk (algo do genero `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`)